# Passing Multiple value to nextview controller

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing an app in which there are three different tables and single UiView which contains label. I want to display name of that  selected table-view cell name set it to the label.

```
    (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
    AppDelegate * appdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    if(appdelegate.btn1)
    {
        appdelegate.selectId=indexPath.row;
        NSLog(@"select Id %d",appdelegate.selectId);    
    }
    else if(appdelegate.btn2)
    {
        appdelegate.selectId=indexPath.row;
        NSLog(@"select Id %d",appdelegate.selectId);
    }
    else if(appdelegate.btn3)
    {
        appdelegate.selectId=indexPath.row;
        NSLog(@"select Id %d",appdelegate.selectId);
    }

    NSString * str=[appdelegate.name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString * str1=[appdelegate.iname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString * str2=[appdelegate.bname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DetailViewController * dvc=[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithTrick:str andOtherString:str1 andOtherString:str2];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];

}
```

And Accessing That cell Name into init method.

```
 -(id)initWithTrick:(NSString *)name_ andOtherString:(NSString *)name2_ andOtherString:(NSString *)name3_;
{
       if (self)
       {

           self.trickname=name_;
           self.trickname2=name2_;
           self.trickname3=name3_;

    }
    return self;


  }
```

Here trickname,trickname2,trickname3 are the NSString.

I have tried this code but not work for me.

please help me out this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this alternatively :

Make three property strings in `DetailViewController.h` class as :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name1;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name2;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name3;
```

and then syntehsize these in `DetailViewController.m` class as :

```
@synthesize name1,name2,name3;
```

and then access these in tableview delegate didselectrow as

```
    DetailViewController * dvc=[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithTrick:str andOtherString:str1 andOtherString:str2];
dvc.name1= str;
dvc.name2= str1;
dvc.name3= str2;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
```

and then access them in your init method.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: declaring that Method into  DetailViewController.h but still not work.

Comment: Plz synthesize in DetailViewController.m     @synthesize name1, name2, name3;

Comment: @yen: synthesize should not be needed anymore... The compiler does that for you ;) @nishant: you mean `NSString` not `NSStrinf`, don't you?

Comment: i am tried this but error thrown by compile  error:-                   Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Comment: In which class are you getting this error ? Are you getting this in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method?

Comment: solve my issue. i am adding that code how to solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
 -(id)initWithTrick:(NSString *)name_ andOtherString:(NSString *)name2_ andOtherString:(NSString *)name3_;
{ 
  self =[super init]; 
   if (self)
   {

       self.trickname=name_;
       self.trickname2=name2_;
       self.trickname3=name3_;

}
return self;
}
```

try this this may help you. your self object not be initialized so the values are not being set in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Leave this all and do like this for passing value to Detailview

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {   
        //do what you did that app delegate thing 

        //now we will pass value which you got from doing stuff above
        //Initialize the detail view controller and display it.
        DetailViewController *dvController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
         // i have just put DetailViewController here as nibname you give name of your detailviewcontrollers XIB

        dvController.trickname = string1;
        dvController.trickname2 = string2;
        dvController.trickname3 =string3;

        // you are passing values of string 1 2 and 3 to detail view controller string trickname, trickname2 and 3

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvController animated:YES];
        [dvController release];

    }
```

### NOTE: trickname,trickname2,trickname3 need to be declared in detail view controller in .h file

Comment: let me know if you get confused somewhere

Comment: i am adding NSString to didSelctRowAtIndexPath like this               NSString * str=[appdelegate.name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSString * str1=[appdelegate.iname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 NSString * str2=[appdelegate.bname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: as your aim is to send data to detail view so i dont understand why you need to add data in app delegate? directly add like i showed above always try not to touch app delegate give it lowest priority

Comment: i am doing to overwrite the detail view init() method and passing parameter so how may i declare the str,str1,str2 to didselect of tableview.

Comment: If i am doing this for single Nsstring work fine and if i am adding 3 string then problem comes

Answer (score 0):

I solve my issue now.

Declare that string  in table view controller

```
{
    NSString * str;
    NSString * str1;
    NSString * str2;
}
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString * str;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString * str1;
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSString * str2;
```

synthesize in .m of table view controller.

```
 @synthesize str,str1,str2;

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {


        AppDelegate * appdelegate=(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

        if(appdelegate.btn1)
        {
            appdelegate.selectId=indexPath.row;
            NSLog(@"select Id %d",appdelegate.selectId);

            str=[appdelegate.name objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

         }

        else if(appdelegate.btn2)
        {
            appdelegate.selectId=indexPath.row;

            NSLog(@"select Id %d",appdelegate.selectId);


            str1=[appdelegate.iname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }

        else if(appdelegate.btn3)
        {

            appdelegate.selectId=indexPath.row;

            NSLog(@"select Id %d",appdelegate.selectId);

                str2=[appdelegate.bname objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        }

    DetailViewController * dvc=[[DetailViewController alloc]initWithTrick:str andOtherString:str1 andOtherString:str2];

        dvc.trickname=str;
        dvc.trickname2=str1;
        dvc.trickname3=str2;

        NSLog(@"%@",str);

        appdelegate.counter=0;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];

  }
```

Then goto Detailview Controller and accessing this 3 strings through init() method of Detailview controller.

1st define that init method in **DetailVewController.h**

```
-(id)initWithTrick:(NSString *)name_ andOtherString:(NSString *)name2_ andOtherString:(NSString *)name3_;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString * trickname;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *  trickname2;

@property(nonatomic,retain)NSString *  trickname3;
```

**DetailViewController.m**

```
@synthesize trickname;
@synthesize trickname2;
@synthesize trickname3;

-(id)initWithTrick:(NSString *)name_ andOtherString:(NSString *)name2_ andOtherString:(NSString *)name3_;

{

    self=[super init];
       if (self)
       {

           self.trickname=name_;
           self.trickname2=name2_;
           self.trickname3=name3_;

    }
    return self;
}
```